# Saving off the current read position so I can seek to it later

Tags: c, io, scanf

I have a program that reads a text file which has a known structure.

For example, I have two integers and one string on each line of the file.

When I use `fscanf` inside a loop, I can regain `n` structures such as I mentioned above. How do I get my current position in the data file, so I store it somewhere, and then later continue reading my text file from where I left off earlier.

Comment: ftell and fseek are right, but as I remember you don't need them, just writing a while loop and reading sequentially does what you need. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Use the ftell() function. It will return the offset in the file.

```
unsigned long position = ftell(file);
```

However, with text files, it is very important to know that ftell() can report the wrong position unless the internal buffer has been cleared. To do this,

```
unsigned long position;
fflush(file);
position = ftell(file);
```

Later, you can use fseek

```
fseek(file,position,SEEK_SET);
```

ftell() told use the offset from the beginning of the file earlier. Here, you use SEEK_SET to indicate that the position you're passing is from the beginning of the file.

EDIT: Richard asked what fflush() does. When you are reading or writing a file, the C library is almost always keeping a buffer of the information. To "flush" that buffer is to write it out to disk, to save any changes. Because of the way the C library is allowed to treat text files, it is possible that this buffer can cause ftell() to report the wrong position unless the buffer is flushed. That is what fflush() does.

Comment: *with text files, it is very important to know that `ftell()` can report the wrong position unless the internal buffer has been cleared* Huh? Not per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4): "The ftell function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. ... For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call;...."

Comment: You wouldn't be opening the file in [update mode with a `+`?](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7)  "When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function"

Comment: And [**NEVER use `fflush()` on a stream in input mode:**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2) "If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"

Answer (score 2):

Use [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) to store the position of the file an [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) to go back to it later.

Answer (score 1):

The process is simple with `ftell` and `fseek`.  See the sample code

```
int i, int1, int2;
FILE *file;
char *str1;

...
// read 10 lines
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
   fscanf(file, "%d %d %s", int1, int2, str1);
}

// save the position;
pos = ftell(file);

// close the file
fclose(file)

...
// later go to that same location after opening the same file
fseek(file, pos, 0);

// continue reading
fscanf(file, "%d %d %s", int1, int2, str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `fflush` before `ftell` to get a file position before reading a record, screws up which record comes next.  In my application, just `ftell` and later `fseek` are working for me.

My mistake was to try using `fsetpos` instead of `fseek`.  The arguments to the former are strange and by forcing the `ftell` output into it caused my application to quit right away (not with a fault, but apparently an EOF I wasn't expecting so soon).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) function

Answer (score 0):

`ftell()` returns a long, which is OK for small files.

For longer files, I use `uint64_t pos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)`, as `lftell()` seems not to exist.